# Camera position when scaling entire scene

Tags: camera

How can I keep my animated camera position after scaling everything I have in the scene?

In the first picture I provided everything is at scale 1. In the second, I scaled everything with 3D cursor as the origin. The camera is not showing the same thing. I guess it is moving because of the set keys in the animation, but I don't know how to make it work the way I want.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Method by Parenting

1. Create an empty at the scene's center.
2. Parent the Camera to the Empty. Select <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> the Camera, <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> the Empty and press <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > *Object*.
3. Select all objects (including the empty) except for the camera and scale them as you intended.